# Horizontal and vertical scrolling issue in a custom react data table component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have developed a custom react data table component which displays `headersData`, `rowData` and `footerData` in the table dynamically.
When it comes to the scrolling I am trying to achieve the below 2 points:

1. **Horizontal scrolling** -
   A) First two columns should be fixed and from third column till the last column, horizontal scrolling should be enabled.
   B) Horizontal scrolling should always be visible at the bottom of the window. There is a max-height of 300px and it should
   be always visible at the bottom.
2. **Vertical scrolling** -
   The header row should be fixed at the top when we are scrolling vertically.

The custom react data table and my attempt is there in the below CodeSandBox link. I have achieved the first point mentioned in Horizontal scrolling but could not achieve the second point mentioned in the horizontal scrolling and the vertical scrolling with the fixed header at the top. Tried for many days and couldn't figure out. For this reason, thought of seeking help and posted the question here. Kindly let me know your thoughts on how we can implement this feature. Thanks in advance.

**CodeSandBox link**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-react-data-table-970ed?file=/src/tableContainer/DataTableContainer.tsx

**Note**: It doesn't need to support in IE.

Expecting the scrolling behavior to be like shown in the below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/6qxcaemu/5